VS Code: Go to Definition from generated C#
In Visual Studio Code, I can perform the command to Go to Definition on a symbol in my solution, even if the symbol is defined in an assembly that is not part of my solution. Depending on whether “Dotnet › Navigation: Navigate To Decompiled Sources” is enabled, VS Code shows generated code from either the assembly’s metadata or a decompilation. In either case, if I try to Go to Definition of a symbol in the generated file, I get the error “No definition found for ‘symbol’”.
Symbol definition traversal is an efficient way to explore an API. It works in Visual Studio. Is there a way to make it work in Visual Studio Code?
